How to ensure that a line drawn with GL_LINES is always visible?
I need to draw a waveform exactly 1 pixel thick like Sound Forge or Wavelab does.
For the example, a stereo sine wave is shown at 1:4 and 1:2 ratios.
(make sure to view the pictures in full size)
Drawing the naive way, from min peak to max peak:

Drawing the right way as explained in this answer:

This is much better except that very close coordinates are culled...
The problem almost vanishes if using very high resolution like 4K:

Please don't suggest a line-strip, although it fixes the issue, it breaks 1-pixel thickness:

There must be a simple approach to solve this but can't figure it out.
